# Transformar objeto em dict no python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, dicionário

Bom time, blz ? Então, comecei a estudar python agora e queria uma ajuda dos senhores na seguinte questão:
Preciso de uma classe que receba dois arrays distintos (palavras e key) e faça a relação entre todos os elementos dos dois arrays, como um dict. ex: Palavra: 'teste' | Key: 1 e armazene essas combinações em uma estrutura de dados, passível de pesquisa, tanto pela palavra como pela key.

```py
class tupla:

    def __init__(self, key, palavra):
        self.key = key
        self.palavra = palavra

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Key: {self.key} | Palavra: {self.palavra} \n'

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você só precisar criar um dicionário, pode usar a função `zip` do Python para relacionar suas duas listas - e não precisa de quase nenhum código:

```
novo_dict = {key: palavra for key, palavra in zip(keys, palavras)}
```

Se quiser realmente uma classe, o minimo que você precisa é usar implementar o
método `__getitem__`.

O exemplo abaixo é bastante ineficiente, mas funcionaria:

```
class MapLists:

    def __init__(self, keys, palavras):
        self.keys = list(keys)
        self.palavras = list(palavras)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keys)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        index = self.keys.index(key)
        return self.palavras[index]
    def to_dict(self):
        return {key: palavra for key, palavra in zip(self.keys, self.palavras)}
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MapLists<{self.to_dict()}>"
```

Nessa classe a correlação de uma lista pra outra é feita apenas no ponto em que se recupera um item, como se fosse um dicionário - então ele faz uma busca na lista de "chaves", e devolve o elemento equivalente na lista de "palavras". Essa estrutura permite que você continue alterando as listas, como listas, enquanto vai usando o objeto, mas é muito, muito mais lenta que um dicionário normal (não vai fazer diferença pra menos de 1000 buscas em menos de 100 items). O método `to_dict` usa  o exemplo que dei anteriormente para criar um dicionário novo com os valores.

Comment: Showw de bola, era exatamente isso que precisa. Desculpa pela leiguice, mas e  quanto ao "main" como faço para passar os dois arrays para a class "MapList", exibir todos os objetos criados e um em específico, através da (key) ? OBS: Pois é consegui fazer o projeto todo sem usar POO, mas esse professor pediu dessa forma.

Comment: isso aí não é so "OOP"  - além do OOP esse código faz uso do método especial `__getitem__` que é sado pelo Python quando você usa seu objeto como um dicionário ou uma lista (com `objeto[chave]`). Não entendi a ideia de "todos os objetos criados" -  você pode por todos os "MapLists" que você cria em uma lista - aí fica com todos eles visíveis. Ou, dentro de um `MapLists",  o método "to_dict" devolve um dicionário onde você tem todos os pares de chave/valor.

Comment: Acho que fica mais fácil exemplificando: tabela = MapLists(listaIndices, listaPalavras)
print(tabela.to_dict()) - O resultado que consigo era exatamente o que queria, mas se eu quiser por exemplo printar o elemento com a key: 10, como faço ?

Comment: Isso: `tabela[10]`

Comment: Foi como tinha tentado, mas dá o seguinte erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/afons/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(tabela[67])
  File "C:\Users\afons\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\tupla.py", line 11, in __getitem__
    index = self.keys.index(key)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: mas -- um "ndarray" não é uma "lista" ? Como o pessoal iniciante costuma usar os termos de forma meio intercambiável, e nao tinha nenhum exemplo de o que eram seus dados, o código foi feito para listas. Se forem arrays unidimensionais, você pode transforma-los em listas no `__init__` - vou mudar o código para isso

Comment: Pô, agora rodou liso demais. Obg mesmo, vc é o cara ! haha

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa criar uma classe nova. Usa as funções built-in do python.

O python já tem uma função pra unir listas. Por exemplo:

```
chave=['a','b','c']
valor=[1,2,3]

d = dict(zip(chave,valor))
```

**Iput**

```
d['a']
```

**Output**

```
1
```

Só com estes comandos você já consegue 'zipar' os conjuntos chave-valor.

Você pode depois usar as chaves pra retornar os valores.

Comment: Pois é, também acredito que não precisava, já conhecia o zip, mas é exigência do professor que seja criado uma classe pra isso, onde cada combinação seja um objeto. pode me ajudar ?